# Do raw HTML in Actionlink

Tags: razor

I have this action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("<i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i>" + ecHelpers.GetLabel("Log out"), "Logout", "MyAccountSurface", new { Class = "" })
```

How can get the html as html and not like <i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases like this you can use `@Url.Action`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "MyAccountSurface")">
    <i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i>@ecHelpers.GetLabel("Log out")
</a>
```

Note: I'm not sure if the call to your `ecHelpers.GetLabel` is syntactically correct here, but you get the idea.

Comment: Oh, simple. i did it as this: `<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "MyAccountSurface")"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> @ecHelpers.GetLabel("Log out")</a>`

Answer (score 0):

typically you'd nest the helper call inside the tag you wish it to display in like:

```
<i class='fa fa-sign-out'>
    @Html.ActionLink(ecHelpers.GetLabel("Log out"), "Logout", "MyAccountSurface", new { Class = "" })
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this extension method to make it easier:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RawActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkHtml, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
        var attributeDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        var concatenatedHtmlAttributes = string.Join(" ", attributeDictionary.Select(a => string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", a.Key, HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(a.Value.ToString()))));            
        var link = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" {1}>{2}</a>", url, concatenatedHtmlAttributes, linkHtml);
        return new MvcHtmlString(link);
    }
```